# Verify Coq proofs in a different language

Tags: coq

Is there support to interpret and verify Coq proofs in a different environment (e.g., Java, C++) other than Coq? An obvious approach is to build a whole interpreter from scratch in say Java, but I wonder what's the minimal to be done.

Comment: Please: accept my answer, or comment it if it is not satisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [Dedukti](https://deducteam.github.io/), a logical framework based on the λΠ-calculus modulo in which many theories and logics can be expressed. In particular [CoqInE](http://www.ensiie.fr/~guillaume.burel/blackandwhite_coqInE.html.en) (Coq In dEdukti) produces Dedukti proofs from Coq proofs.